# ASP.net setting name to id for input check boxes

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a aspx page which has several check boxes that are grouped together by the same name and each check box has a different id, but for some reason if i run my webpage in visual studio it sets the name of each check box to it's id any idea why this could be?

For example from the below check boxes the first check box with id 'c1' will have it's name changed to 'c1'.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="group1" id="c1"  value="c1" runat="server" />
<input type="checkbox" name="group1" id="c2"  value="c2" runat="server" />
<input type="checkbox" name="group1" id="c3"  value="c3" runat="server" />
```

Comment: please show your source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do not use `runat="server"` in `input tag` like below:

Try it.
HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="group1" id="c1"  value="c1" runat="server"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="group1" id="c2"  value="c2" runat="server"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="group1" id="c3"  value="c3" runat="server"/>
```

I did also mistake but we should not use `runat="server"` attribute in html input tag in Asp.net.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="c1" text="c1" runat="server" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="c2" text="c2" runat="server" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="c3" text="c3" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Using group name does seem to allow me to retain a common name across the check boxes thanks for that. Any idea why ASP.net shows this behavior of replacing the name with the id?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use radio button instead of checkbox?

Please check this

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="c1" groupname="test" value="c1" runat="server" />
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="c2" groupname="test" value="c2" runat="server" />
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="c3" groupname="test" value="c3" runat="server" />
```